# Flipboard RSS account

Tags: rss, feedly

How can I add my RSS account to Flipboard? I have my twitter,  Facebook and YouTube accounts on Flipboard,  but my RSS feeds, from my old Google RSS, are now on Feedly,  and I would like the feeds to be in Flipboard as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I use this technique from this page http://labnol.blogspot.in/2007/10/merge-multiple-rss-feeds-feedburner-mix.html to aggregate my feeds in feedburner and feed them to Flipboard.

> Step 1: Go to the Yahoo! Pipes website and Create a new Yahoo! Pipe.
>
> Step 2: Drag-n-drop the "Fetch Feed" tab from the Sources tab to the
>   main drawing panel.
>
> Step 3: Add all the different Feed URLs in the same Fetch Feed Module
>   (click the plus icon).
>
> Step 4: Once you are done adding all your RSS feeds, drag the lower
>   circle from Feed Fetch module to the Pipe Output at the bottom.
>
> Step 5: Give some name and save this Yahoo! Pipe. Now run the pipe and
>   you will see a new RSS feed - syndicate that feed via FeedBurner so
>   you can even track the feed subscribers. It's all very simple.